# How do we know yo-yo is rolling without slipping?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

How do we know a prior that a typical yo-yo rolls without slipping when released?

Now suppose we get a typical yoyo which is attached to the string (otherwise it would just fall and hit the ground if you released it!), then I cut the string so its not attached the to yoyo anymore. Then I dip the string in slippery oil and wrap the yoyo again with the string unattached.  Could slipping occur after release as the string unravels?

How do you test experimentally whether we have rolling without slipping?

Comment: Would you mind clarifying this sentence or drawing a sketch: "*If you have a yoyo and you do not attach the string at its end to the yoyo, and the string is laced with slippery oil, will we have rolling with slipping upon release?*"

Comment: @Steeven Basically we get a typical yoyo which is attached to the string (otherwise it would just fall and hit the ground if you released it!), then I cut the string so its not attached the to yoyo anymore.  Then I dip the string in slippery oil and wrap the yoyo again with the string unattached.

Answer (score -1):

Rolling without slipping occurs if the rotational velocity of the yo-yo matches that of its angular velocity i.e. v=wr.

This; however, is complicated by the fact that for a yoyo the radius will change as the spooled string unwinds.

In this case you want to determine a relationship between r and the length wound.

Comment: You just cited the mathematical condition for rolling without slipping.  What I'm saying is how do we know in the first place that yoyo situation is when we have rolling without slipping?

Comment: You have that situation when the condition is satisfied. I fail to see what your angling for as you did ask for how we can tell experimentally.

Comment: Ok so we dont know a prior, we first have to see whether the condition is satisfied?